# Replace string in bash script

Tags: command-line, bash

I tried the following command in my script:

```
find=grep "$jasper" jasperreports.properties | awk -F"reports/" '{print $2}'
```

Example output:

```
maps
```

I want to change this output to something else, e.g. `charts`. For that, I tried:

```
sed -i /"$find"/charts
```

`sed` is causing me problems, it needs an input file but I don't have one. Is there a way to pipe the output from grep and awk to sed?

Comment: (editing note) use two spaces instead of `<br>` for a line break, indent a string with four spaces and a newline before it to show it as code.

Comment: The use of grep, awk AND sed here makes it sound like you're doing this backwards (and `grep | awk` is pointless). It can probably be done with a single awk or sed. If you show some sample data and wanted output we might help you with that.

Comment: @geirha , thanks have a look my solution , any comment is acceptable ....thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-i` can only be used with sed if you're passing a file, it means "inline replace". Without this, the output of sed would be written to `stdout` (usually the console output). With `-i`, it does an *inline replacement*, that is, doing replacements in the file itself.

The next code reads the contents of `jasperreports.properties` into the variable `$input` (line 1) and finds the string to be replaced (line 2).
On the third line, it outputs the input string and pipes it through `sed` for replacement. `sed` outputs the string to `stdout` which will be caught by `$(` and `)`, and therefore be stored in `$input`.

```
read input < jasperreports.properties
find=$(grep "$jasper" jasperreports.properties | awk -F"reports/" '{print $2}')
input=$(echo "$input" | sed "s/$find/charts/")
```

If you want to apply the changes immediately to the file:

```
find=$(grep "$jasper" jasperreports.properties | awk -F"reports/" '{print $2}')
sed "s/$find/charts/" -i jasperreports.properties
```

From [`man sed`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man1/sed.1.html):

```
   s/regexp/replacement/
          Attempt   to   match  regexp  against  the  pattern  space.   If
          successful, replace that portion matched with replacement.   The
          replacement may contain the special character & to refer to that
          portion of the pattern space  which  matched,  and  the  special
          escapes  \1  through  \9  to refer to the corresponding matching
          sub-expressions in the regexp.
```

Comment: but jasperreports.properties file will not changed !

Comment: I thought you wanted to store the output in a string. Added code for inline replacement.

Comment: first of all your answer was helpful , but i want replace it in file jasperreports.properties as well.

Comment: @moata_u: like I said, I've added the code for that in the answer. It looks like `sed "s/$find/charts/" -i jasperreports.properties`. Note that only one replacement per line is made.

Answer (score 1):

You can always provide a pseudo-file with the `< <(command)` [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) syntax:

```
sed -e "/$find/charts" < <(grep "$jasper" jasperreports.properties | awk -F"reports/" '{print $2}')
```

Comment: i tried : sed -i "/"$edit"/c charts" < <(edit=`grep "$jasper" jasperreports.properties | awk -F"reports/" '{print $2}'`)     seems not working !!

Comment: Sorry, fixed - You shouldn't assign the result to a variable.

Comment: Minus for linking to a page that gives partly wrong information and exercises bad practice. It's best to avoid the advanced bash scripting guide unless you know how to filter out the junk. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution gives a correct and more complete explanation of process substitution. Also, `grep|awk` is silly; let awk do the "greping".

Answer (score 0):

```
jasper=( maps charts widgets )
jasper1=( Maps Charts Widgets )


count=${#jasper[*]}            
jasper_path=`find . -type f -name 'jasperreports.properties'`

count=${#jasper[*]}
for (( i=0;i<$count;i++ )); do
sed -i "/${jasper[i]}.base/c com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.fusion.${jasper[i]}.base.swf.url=https://$host/webcare/reports/${jasper1[i]}" $jasper_path
done
```

**other solution ()**
`find=$(grep "maps.base" jasperreport.properties | awk -F"reports/" '{print $2}';sed "s/$find/$host/" jasperreport.properties > tmp.txt.txt && mv tmp.txt jasperreport.properties`

**what am trying to do is the following :**
1.find all files in directory that have name jasperreport.properties(which include 3 lines as you see from previous code ,three lines same only different word"maps,charts,widgets" ) 

2.point to each line individually and change host ip address for 3 three lines , with take concern of keeping "maps,charts,widgets" in the middle and "Maps,Charts,Widgets" at the end and as you see the 3 words at the end start with capital ...

Comment: Well there you go, one sed, that's much better :). You could do it all in one line, using find and GNU sed: `find . -type f -name jasperreport.properties -exec sed -r -i "s#^([^=]*\.)(maps|charts|widgets)(\.base\.swf\.url).*#\1\2\3=https://$host/webcare/reports/\u\2#" {} +`

Comment: :)...wonderful...that work 100% perfectly in ubuntu , i will make some changes your code try not use -i option other wise script will not work in solaris...

Comment: i isn't the only part that isn't portable there. Solaris's sed also don't know extended regular expressions, which was used there (-r enables ERE). A portable solution is harder. Your approach in the answer is closer to a portable solution.